# spdata target attribute - conflict while deploying

Tags: deployment

I copied project items (empty elements) from one location to another to reuse them, and when I deployed, I got an error saying:  `Both [Name1] and [Name1] contain a file that deploys to the same Package location: [Location]`

I know I had this error before, and I had to go to Target attribute in spdata for each file to make it unique, but what does this target mean? I am changing stuff but I would like to understand what this change means? where will this value of `"target"` be deployed and how is it making a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any official documentation on that just now, but as far as I know it refers to the location within the SharePoint deployment package, that means within the .wsp file. If you open that file (for example, after changing the file extension to .cab), you can see its internal folder structure.

This structure often (as long as the `Type` attribute of the `ProjectItemFolder` or `ProjectItemFile` node is `TemplateFile`) corresponds to the structure of the `TEMPLATE` folder in the SharePoint hive (I mean `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE`), like `Images`, `Layouts`, `FEATURES\YourFeatureNameHere`, but there are exceptions as well, where the `Type` attribute is `ElementManifest`. These refer to SharePoint element items, stored in separate folders in the .wsp files as well.

Hopefully it helps you to understand the conflicts better.